# Is it possible to define variables if a condition is satisfied in karate framework?

Tags: karate

Eg. If insurance = true(in JSON response) then def variables(insurance_img_cancel, insurance_img_refund, insurance_details etc.) from api response (which will be used in next api in the chain) else throw message "Insurance unavailable".

```
Given url postEligibility
And def eligibilityRequestBody = read('eligibilityCPReq.json')
And request eligibilityRequestBody
And print eligibilityRequestBody
And def cookie = read('cookie.txt')
And header cookie = cookie
When method Post
Then status 200 
And print response
And match **response.data.insuranceAvailable == 'true'**
And def insurance_img_cancel = response.data.img_cancel
And def insurance_img_refund = response.data.img_refund
And def insurance_details = response.data.insurance_details
And def insurance_end_date = response.data.insurance_end_date
And def insurance_id = response.data.insurance_details[0].insurance_id
And def insurance_premium = response.data.insurance_details[0].premium
And def insurance_type = response.data.insurance_type
And def insuranceAvailable = response.data.insuranceAvailable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that `match` sufficient:

And match response.data.insuranceAvailable == 'true'

So if it is not true it will fail the test. That's what you want right ?

Else please simplify the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Peter for developing such a simplified and effective API automation framework.